# Blender Python: trying to create an animation from a list of locations

Tags: python, animation

I'm trying to animate an object based on locations in a list I imported. I want the code to take the active object, move its Z location to the first value in a list, add a keyframe, advance two frames, and repeat for the next value in the list, and repeat until it reaches the end of the list.

My current code does the first step as I intended, but for every iteration after the first, it doesn't seem to move the object. It still adds every keyframe like I intended, and when I added a print line for each iteration, it seems to be working through the list, but for some reason it only moves the selected object on the first iteration.

I checked and the list imported correctly and has no headers or anything.

The variables:

> col1 = the list of locations ("column 1")

> Row_Count = a variable initialized at 0

> Frame_Count = a variable initialized at 1

The code:

```
for i in range(len(col1)):

    # Go to frame
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = Frame_Count

# ***THIS SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM:***
    # Move to list value:
    bpy.context.object.location[2] = col1[Row_Count]

    # Add keyframe:
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name(type="Location")

    #Update row count:
    Row_Count += 1

    # Update frame (advancing by 2, looks better as animation):
    Frame_Count += 2
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it depends what you are doing "after" your code. If you want to see the animation in the viewport - then this is the wrong way to do it. You would have to add keyframes. Then it will work. If you are rendering after your last line in the loop - it might work

Comment: btw you can use `for row_count in range(len(col1)):` that way you can use the iteration index that gets automatically increased with each loop. and you don't need `Frame_Count` you can simply use `bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 1 + row_count  * 2`

Comment: Thanks @Chris! That got me through this problem. Now onto the next one :)